# sass импорт по маске

Tags: gulp, sass, scss

app.scss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
gulp.task('styles', () => (
gulp.src('app/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: errorHandler(`Error in \'styles\' task`)}))
    .pipe(gulpIf(isDebug, sourcemaps.init()))
    .pipe(sass({
        errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulpIf(!isDebug, gcmq()))
    .pipe(gulpIf(!isDebug, nano({zindex: false})))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', basename: "app"}))
    .pipe(gulpIf(isDebug, sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/styles'))
));
```

Как можно реализовать импорт по маске внутри scss? 
Если меняю путь в таске на 
    app/styles/app.scss

то

```
app/style.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../blocks/**/*.scss
   Parent style sheet: ../templates/app/styles/app.scss
    on line 5 of app/styles/app.scss
>> @import '../blocks/**/*.scss';
   ^
```

Может есть какое-то красивое решение?

Дерево выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может вы не заметили, но ошибка падает не в строке маски, а то что файл не может найти `/jeet/index`. Помню https://github.com/rails/sass-rails тут была возможность импорта по маске. 100% есть такая реализация, надо поискать. Но это вроде и в дефолте должно работать, или я ошибаюсь? https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1094

Comment: странно, а почему не смогло найти? Когда пишу gulp.src('app/styles/app.scss') находит а если gulp.src('app/**/*.scss'), то нет

Comment: видимо по дефолту не работает  тк у меня IDE подсвечивает как ошибку

Comment: пути всегда относительные, возможно он идет не туда, внутри ide своя структура путей, при сборках другая. Кстати при импорте через /**/* не указывается расширение, возможно это и не важно